# Why always UpperCase in my code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
<input id=a type="text" value='sss'/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#a').keyup(
  function(event){
   alert(String.fromCharCode(event.which))
  })
</script>
```

you can test this code in your brower,

and it always alert UpperCase of a charcode.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At first I thought this was a bug, as the expected lowercase value is returned for the `keypress` event. It turns out that on `keyup/keydown` the ASCII uppercase/non-shifted version of a key is always returned.

From this link: http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/eventkeyboardmouse.shtml

> Be careful when accessing the keyCode
>   property during an onkeydown or
>   onkeyup event, as it is set whenever
>   any key is pressed, including non
>   character keys like "Shift". This
>   means if you try to press "Shift+a" to
>   try and get the keyCode for "A", you
>   will always end up getting two
>   keyCodes instead, one for "Shift" and
>   one for "A" in that order. What you
>   won't get regardless is the keyCode
>   for "a", **as keyCode always returns
>   the unicode value of the uppercase
>   version of a character**

- Pressing Shift+a counts as a single `keypress` event.
- Pressing Shift+a counts as two `keydown` events when the keys are pressed down and two `keyup` event when the keys are released.
- `keypress` returns the *composite* value of one or more keys being pressed in unison.
- `keydown` and `keyup` return the value of a *single key* while ignoring any key combinations.

Now here's the confusing part: for some reason the unshifted value of the `a` key is returned as key code 65. But 65 is uppercase A in the ASCII table. So somewhere along the line the browser is taking the lowercase a (ASCII code 97), transforming it to uppercase A, then passing it `keydown/keyup` as the non-shifted character. Weird, isn't it?

Comment: Not sure if I'd call the behavior "weird", it's just a convention. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.charCode notes that the case is not respected for `keyCode` events. A `keyCode` tells you which *key* was pressed, not the character that results from it. And since all the letters are printed in upper case on virtually all keyboards, it seems to make sense to use the upper case variant. Nice answer otherwise. :)

Answer (score 1):

(guess)

It's referencing the *Key* which doesn't have a case.  Case is determined by whether or not the shift key is also down.