# Ext JS - Problems getting the real char typed ?

Tags: extjs, textfield, uppercase

Here is my problem... Considering this code...

```
'keydown': function (textThis,e) {
    var cc = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
    Ext.MessageBox.alert('Caracter',cc);
}
```

I always get the the char I type but in uppercase... Even if I type it in minus... How can I solve this ?. Thankx in adavnce from Cordoba Argentina

Comment: Upvote for being from a cool place ;)

Answer (score 6):

The `keydown` and `keyup` events fire for every single keystroke (e.g. for the `shift` key as well). They report the *key* (the 'key' doesn't have a lower or upper-case). `keypress` reports a single event for combined strokes (e.g. SHIFT plus A) and the ASCII code (with correct representation of upper/lower case).

The solution is to listen to the `keypress` event. If you are supporting older browsers you should go with this code (according to [this website](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html)):

```
String.fromCharCode(evt.charCode || evt.keyCode);
```

More details in [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263889/why-always-uppercase-in-my-code).

Comment: Please accept the answer then, and maybe upvote as well. I'm new to SO, I still need the reputation points ;)